# AES encryption in NI LabVIEW

Tags: c#, aes, labview

How do I implement AES encryption and decryption in [LabVIEW](http://www.ni.com/en-in/shop/labview.html) and configure the following settings?

1. Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
2. Mode = CipherMode.CBC
3. Key Size = 128
4. Block Size = 128

I have tried few option over here [Igor Titov](https://github.com/IgorTitov/LabVIEW-Advanced-Encryption-Standard), [AES Crypto Toolkit by Alab Technologies](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/214328)
Tried to reach both parties to confirm if those toolkits support above configuration, but they don't respond on phone or email.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I found this code from [Igor Titov](https://github.com/IgorTitov/LabVIEW-Advanced-Encryption-Standard)

Encrypt:https://github.com/IgorTitov/LabVIEW-Advanced-Encryption-Standard/blob/master/Encrypt%20with%20AES.vi

```
/** 
     * Encrypt a text using AES encryption in Counter mode of operation
     *
     * Unicode multi-byte character safe
     *
     * @param plaintext Source text to be encrypted
     * @param password  The password to use to generate a key
     * @param nBits     Number of bits to be used in the key (128, 192, or 256)
     * @returns         Encrypted text
     */


    public function encrypt(plaintext : String, password : String, nBits : int) : String //Done in LV
    {
           var blockSize : int = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
        if (!(nBits == BIT_KEY_128 || nBits == BIT_KEY_192 || nBits == BIT_KEY_256)) 
  {
                 // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
              throw new Error("Must be a key mode of either 128, 192, 256 bits");
        }
        plaintext = Utf8.encode(plaintext);
        password = Utf8.encode(password);

        // use AES itself to encrypt password to get cipher key (using plain password as source for key 
        // expansion) - gives us well encrypted key
        var nBytes : int = nBits / 8;  // no bytes in key
        var pwBytes : Array = new Array(nBytes);
        for (var i : int = 0;i < nBytes;i++) 
        {
               pwBytes[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var key : Array = cipher(pwBytes, keyExpansion(pwBytes));  // gives us 16-byte key

        key = key.concat(key.slice(0, nBytes - 16));  // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long

        // initialise counter block (NIST SP800-38A §B.2): millisecond time-stamp for nonce in 1st 8 bytes,
        // block counter in 2nd 8 bytes
        var counterBlock : Array = new Array(blockSize);
        var nonce : int = 123456789;////DEBUG!!!(new Date()).getTime();  // timestamp: milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970
        var nonceSec : int = Math.floor(nonce / 1000);
        var nonceMs : int = nonce % 1000;

        // encode nonce with seconds in 1st 4 bytes, and (repeated) ms part filling 2nd 4 bytes
        for (i = 0;i < 4;i++) 
        {
               counterBlock[i] = (nonceSec >>> (i * 8)) & 0xff;             
        }

        for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
        {
               counterBlock[i + 4] = nonceMs & 0xff;
        } 
        // and convert it to a string to go on the front of the ciphertext
        var ctrTxt : String = '';
        for (i = 0;i < 8;i++) 
        {
               ctrTxt += String.fromCharCode(counterBlock[i]);
        }
        // generate key schedule - an expansion of the key into distinct Key Rounds for each round
        var keySchedule : Array = keyExpansion(key);
        var blockCount : int = Math.ceil(plaintext.length / blockSize);
        var ciphertxt : Array = new Array(blockCount);  // ciphertext as array of strings

        for (var b : int = 0;b < blockCount;b++) 
        {
               // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
               // done in two stages for 32-bit ops: using two words allows us to go past 2^32 blocks (68GB)
               for (var c : int = 0;c < 4;c++) 
            {
                    counterBlock[15 - c] = (b >>> (c * 8)) & 0xff;                  
        }

            for (c = 0;c < 4;c++) 
            {
                    counterBlock[15 - c - 4] = (b / 0x100000000 >>> c * 8);
            }

            var cipherCntr : Array = cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // -- encrypt counter block --

            // block size is reduced on final block
            var blockLength : int = b < blockCount - 1 ? blockSize : (plaintext.length - 1) % blockSize + 1;
            var cipherChar : Array = new Array(blockLength);

            for (i = 0;i < blockLength;i++) 
            {  
                // -- xor plaintext with ciphered counter char-by-char --
                cipherChar[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ plaintext.charCodeAt(b * blockSize + i);                    
                //trace("i=",i,"plaintext.charCodeAt(b * blockSize + i)",plaintext.charCodeAt(b * blockSize + i),"cipherChar[i]=",cipherChar[i]);
                cipherChar[i] = String.fromCharCode(cipherChar[i]);

            }

            ciphertxt[b] = cipherChar.join(''); 
            //trace(ciphertxt);
        }

        // Array.join is more efficient than repeated string concatenation in IE
        var ciphertext : String = ctrTxt + ciphertxt.join('');
        //trace("before 64 encode:",ciphertext);
        ciphertext = Base64.encode(ciphertext);  // encode in base64
           //trace("after 64 encode:",ciphertext);
           //alert((new Date()) - t);

        return ciphertext;
    }
```

Decrypt: https://github.com/IgorTitov/LabVIEW-Advanced-Encryption-Standard/blob/master/Decrypt%20with%20AES.vi

```
/** 
         * Decrypt a text encrypted by AES in counter mode of operation
         *
         * @param ciphertext Source text to be encrypted
         * @param password   The password to use to generate a key
         * @param nBits      Number of bits to be used in the key (128, 192, or 256)
         * @returns          Decrypted text
         */
        public function decrypt(ciphertext : String, password : String, nBits : int) : String 
  {
            var blockSize : int = 16;  // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
            if (!(nBits == BIT_KEY_128 || nBits == BIT_KEY_192 || nBits == BIT_KEY_256)) {
                  // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
                  throw new Error("Must be a key mode of either 128, 192, 256 bits");
            }

            ciphertext = Base64.decode(ciphertext.split("\n").join(""));
            password = Utf8.encode(password);
            //var t = new Date();  // timer

            // use AES to encrypt password (mirroring encrypt routine)
            var nBytes : int = nBits / 8;  // no bytes in key
            var pwBytes : Array = new Array(nBytes);
            for (var i : int = 0;i < nBytes;i++) 
            {
                pwBytes[i] = isNaN(password.charCodeAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var key : Array = cipher(pwBytes, keyExpansion(pwBytes));
            key = key.concat(key.slice(0, nBytes - 16));  // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long

            // recover nonce from 1st 8 bytes of ciphertext
            var counterBlock : Array = new Array(8);
            var ctrTxt : String = ciphertext.slice(0, 8);
            for (i = 0;i < 8;i++) 
            {
                counterBlock[i] = ctrTxt.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            // generate key schedule
            var keySchedule : Array = keyExpansion(key);

            // separate ciphertext into blocks (skipping past initial 8 bytes)
            var nBlocks : int = Math.ceil((ciphertext.length - 8) / blockSize);
            var ct : Array = new Array(nBlocks);
            for (b = 0;b < nBlocks;b++) 
            {
                ct[b] = ciphertext.slice(8 + b * blockSize, 8 + b * blockSize + blockSize);

                //trace("ct[b]=",ct[b],"blockSize=",blockSize,8 + b * blockSize, 8 + b * blockSize + blockSize);
            }
            //var temp:String=ct[1];
//          for (var i:int=0;i<temp.length;i++)
//          {
//              trace("ct[1]Byte Array:",temp.charCodeAt(i));
//          }

            var ciphertextArr : Array = ct;  // ciphertext is now array of block-length strings

            // plaintext will get generated block-by-block into array of block-length strings
            var plaintxt : Array = new Array(ciphertextArr.length);

            for (var b : int = 0;b < nBlocks;b++) 
            {
                // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
                for (var c : int = 0;c < 4;c++) 
                   {
                        counterBlock[15 - c] = ((b) >>> c * 8) & 0xff;
                }
                for (c = 0;c < 4;c++) 
                {
                        counterBlock[15 - c - 4] = (((b + 1) / 0x100000000 - 1) >>> c * 8) & 0xff;
                }
                //trace(counterBlock);
                var cipherCntr : Array = cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);  // encrypt counter block
                //trace(cipherCntr);
                var plaintxtByte : Array = new Array(String(ciphertextArr[b]).length);
                for (i = 0;i < String(ciphertextArr[b]).length;i++) 
                {
                    // -- xor plaintxt with ciphered counter byte-by-byte --
                    plaintxtByte[i] = cipherCntr[i] ^ String(ciphertextArr[b]).charCodeAt(i);
                    //trace("i=",i,"plaintxtByte[i]=",plaintxtByte[i],"cipherCntr[i]=",cipherCntr[i],"String(ciphertextArr[b]).charCodeAt(i)=",String(ciphertextArr[b]).charCodeAt(i));
                    //trace(plaintxtByte[i]);
                    plaintxtByte[i] = String.fromCharCode(plaintxtByte[i]);

                }
                plaintxt[b] = plaintxtByte.join('');
            }

            // join array of blocks into single plaintext string
            var plaintext : String = plaintxt.join('');
            plaintext = Utf8.decode(plaintext);  // decode from UTF8 back to Unicode multi-byte chars
            return plaintext;
        }
```

Not sure what programming language is this. If I can get help in converting this code to C# that will solve my blocker.

Here is the VI snippet.

[image]

Comment: This looks like ActionScript, but I've never worked with that language before, so I could be wrong. The links in your question to Igor's repo point to LabVIEW source VI files, not these functions. Where did those come from?

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen In that LabView file he added this code as description. Added a image of that vi block diagram, please check

Comment: @HaBo let me know if the answer helped, otherwise I can write the padding if you're stuck. S

Comment: @SeanJ I am kind of stuck. If you can share with padding that will help.

Comment: @HaBo Short on time at the moment but you might like to try : https://lavag.org/files/file/198-encryption/

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with blowfish but am not familiar with the AES implementation by Alab Tech.
Assuming the Alab Tech library function correctly, just pad your data as necessary before encrypting it.

> KCS7 (described in RFC 5652). This pads data to the blocksize with the
>   number that is equal to the number of added bytes. If the original
>   data is an integer multiple of N bytes, then an extra block of bytes
>   with value N is added

That sounds relatively straightforward and a simple block diagram as below shows how it might work:

[image]